# Python OpenCV - Display Bad Pixels Inspection Test

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning, vision

I want to find every bad pixels present in a display. A bad pixel can be a pixel with the incorrect color or if the pixel is just black. The Display has 160x320 pixels as dimensions. So if the display is good, must have 160*320 = 51200 pixels. If the display does not has 51200 pixels then is bad. Also, i want to know the position of every bad pixel.

Once the images taken are too large, I will share a google drive shared folder with examples of good displays and bad displays containing bad pixels.

[Displays Images](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EdG6AXmtEoyjv24bXutB1HKioRfphaTA?usp=sharing)

Can you please help me how to do this? I want to do this in python with opencv.

Grateful in advance

I've tried to evaluate by contours of the detected objects and it works but only if all pixels are present. If a pixel is missing and didn't detect contours, i can know that a pixel is missing, but im not able to know the position of it.

So I think that the best solution is to trace a grid and evaluate every cell of the grid.

Here is my current code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def getColor(area):
    if area > 70:
        return (255, 0, 0)
    if area < 14:
        return (0, 0, 255)
    return (255, 255, 0)

def test_green_pattern():

    mask = cv2.imread("masks/mask.bmp", 0)
    green = cv2.imread("images/green-good.bmp")

    green_W = cv2.addWeighted(green, 3, green, 0, 1)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(green_W, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    masked = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, gray, mask=mask)
    cv2.imwrite("try/green-masked.bmp", masked)
    # Real threshold = 120
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(masked, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    cv2.imwrite("try/green-threshold.bmp", thresh)

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    print("Green Pattern Pixels:", len(contours))
    areas = []
    perimeters = []
    bad = 0
    prob_double = 0
    qtd = 0
    for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
        area = area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        areas.append(area)
        perimeter = cv2.arcLength(contour,True)
        perimeters.append(perimeter)
        color = getColor(area)

        if area < 14:   
            bad += 1
            qtd += 1
            x, y, width, height = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            roi = green[y:y+height, x:x+width]
            cv2.imwrite("try/temp/"+str(i)+".bmp", roi) 
            cv2.drawContours(green, contour, -1, color, 1)
            cv2.drawContours(green_W, contour, -1, color, 1)
        if area > 90:   
            prob_double += 1
            qtd += 2
            cv2.drawContours(green, contour, -1, color, 1)
            cv2.drawContours(green_W, contour, -1, color, 1)
        else:
            qtd += 1
    #get_statistics(areas, perimeters)
    print("Total:",qtd)
    print("Probably double pixel:", prob_double)
    print("Bad pixels:", bad)
    cv2.imwrite("try/green-contours.bmp", green)
    cv2.imwrite("try/green_w-contours.bmp", green_W)

test_green_pattern()
```

Comment: plz share a google drive shared folder with example of masks/mask.bmp

Comment: Can't you just do cv2.absdiff() to find the bad pixels?

Comment: @kenash0625 I've just uploaded

Answer (score 0):

@Guilherme Mendes

**Edited:take less time to compute.  green-bad.bmp:35sec--->5sec**

1.find contour centroid

2.find centroid points in the same column

3.insert point at

> bad pixels

connect

> good/bad pixels

with blue/red line

input:green-bad.bmp

output:
c,r= 211 , 30
c,r= 211 , 30

input:green-good.bmp

output:none

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include<list>
#include <iterator>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

class MyPoint3
{
public:
    MyPoint3(int _x=0,int _y=0,int _z=0):x(_x),y(_y),z(_z)
    {}
    int x, y, z;
    Point cvPoint()
    {
        return Point(x, y);
    }
    bool operator==(const MyPoint3& rhs)
    {
        return x == rhs.x && y == rhs.y && z == rhs.z;
    }
    MyPoint3(const MyPoint3& rhs)
    {
        x = rhs.x;
        y = rhs.y;
        z = rhs.z;
    }
    MyPoint3&operator=(const MyPoint3& rhs)
    {
        x = rhs.x;
        y = rhs.y;
        z = rhs.z;
        return *this;
    }
};
void findnearpts(vector<MyPoint3>&col,vector<MyPoint3>&pts, MyPoint3 ptrun)
{
    vector<MyPoint3> nearpts;
    pts.erase(find(pts.begin(), pts.end(), ptrun));
    col.push_back(ptrun);

    size_t j = 0;
    for (;j < pts.size()  ; j++)
    {
        auto iter0 = pts.at(j);
        if (iter0.x - ptrun.x > -8)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    for (; j < pts.size()  ; j++)
    {
        auto iter0 = pts.at(j);
        if (iter0.x - ptrun.x > 8)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (fabs(ptrun.y - iter0.y) < 20)
        {
            nearpts.push_back(iter0);
        }
    }
    for (auto& a : nearpts)
    {
        findnearpts(col,pts, a);
    }
}
int main2(int argc,  char* argv[]);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString str = "c:/Users/qt/Downloads/Displays-20230404T035654Z-001/Displays/";
    auto src = imread((str + "green-bad.bmp").toUtf8().constData());
    //addWeighted(src, 3, src, 0, 1,src);
    imwrite((str + "green-bad-strong.bmp").toUtf8().constData(), src);
    Mat dst, dst2,dst3;
    // You can try more different parameters
    cvtColor(src, dst, COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 0);
    imwrite((str + "green-bad-gray.bmp").toUtf8().constData(), dst);
    threshold(dst, dst2, 41, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
    imwrite((str + "green-bad-binary.bmp").toUtf8().constData(), dst2);

    //morphologyEx(dst2, dst3, MORPH_CLOSE, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(6,6)));
    //imwrite((str + "green-bad-binary-closing.bmp").toUtf8().constData(), dst3);
    //main2(argc, argv);
    vector<vector<Point> > contours0;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(dst2, contours0, hierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    Mat matpt(src.size(), CV_8UC3,Scalar(0,0,0));
    typedef cv::Point3_<uint8_t> Pixel;
    vector<MyPoint3> points;
    for (auto& a : contours0)
    {
        auto M = moments(a);
        auto cx = int(M.m10 / M.m00);
        auto cy = int(M.m01 / M.m00);
        points.push_back(MyPoint3(cx, cy,0));
        line(matpt, Point(cx, cy), Point(cx, cy), Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    }
    imwrite((str + "green-bad-center.bmp").toUtf8().constData(), matpt);
    std::sort(points.begin(), points.end(), [&](MyPoint3 a, MyPoint3 b) {return a.x < b.x; });

    const int height = 160,width=320;


    vector<vector<MyPoint3>> cols;
    cols.reserve(width);
    for (;!points.empty();)
    {
        vector<MyPoint3> tmpcol;
        findnearpts(tmpcol, points, points[0]);
        cols.push_back(tmpcol);
    }
    qDebug() << "test1" << endl;
    for (auto& colrun : cols)
    {
        std::sort(colrun.begin(), colrun.end(), [&](MyPoint3 a, MyPoint3 b) {return a.y < b.y; });
    }
    qDebug() << "test2" << endl;
    for (int nfind = 1; nfind;)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < cols.size(); i++)
        {
            if (cols.at(i).size() != height)
            {
                nfind = 1;
                for (size_t j = 0; j < cols.size(); j++)
                {
                    if (i != j
                        && cols.at(j).size() != height
                        &&
                        (fabs(cols.at(i).begin()->x - cols.at(j).rbegin()->x) < 8
                            || fabs(cols.at(i).rbegin()->x - cols.at(j).begin()->x) < 8
                            )
                        )
                    {
                        vector<MyPoint3> tmppts;
                        if (cols.at(i).begin()->y < cols.at(j).begin()->y)
                        {
                            tmppts.insert(tmppts.end(), cols.at(i).begin(), cols.at(i).end());
                            tmppts.insert(tmppts.end(), MyPoint3(cols.at(j).begin()->x, .5 * (cols.at(j).begin()->y + cols.at(i).rbegin()->y), 1));
                            tmppts.insert(tmppts.end(), cols.at(j).begin(), cols.at(j).end());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tmppts.insert(tmppts.end(), cols.at(j).begin(), cols.at(j).end());
                            tmppts.insert(tmppts.end(), MyPoint3(cols.at(i).begin()->x, .5 * (cols.at(j).rbegin()->y + cols.at(i).begin()->y), 1));
                            tmppts.insert(tmppts.end(), cols.at(i).begin(), cols.at(i).end());
                        }
                        if (i > j)
                        {
                            cols.erase(cols.begin() + i);
                            cols.erase(cols.begin() + j);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cols.erase(cols.begin() + j);
                            cols.erase(cols.begin() + i);
                        }
                        cols.push_back(tmppts);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                nfind = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    qDebug() << "test3" << endl;
    std::sort(cols.begin(), cols.end(), [&](vector<MyPoint3>& a, vector<MyPoint3>& b) {return a.at(0).x < b.at(0).x; });
    qDebug() << "test4" << endl;
    int colnumber = 0;
    for (auto& colrun : cols)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i+1 < colrun.size(); i++)
        {
            MyPoint3 p1 = colrun.at(i), p2 = colrun.at(i + 1);
            Scalar sc(255, 0, 0);
            if (p1.z || p2.z)
            {
                sc = Scalar(0, 0, 255);
                qDebug() << "c,r=" << colnumber << "," << (p1.z?i:i+1) << endl;
            }
            line(src,p1.cvPoint() ,p2.cvPoint(), sc);
        }
        colnumber++;
    }
    imwrite((str + "green-bad-cols.bmp").toUtf8().constData(), src);
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution! It actualy works! The problem is that it takes about 5 minutes to compute this code... I've tried to optimize it, but without success... What do you suggest? Can you help me here?

Comment: I tried to optimize it, now it takes less time to compute .       @GuilhermeMendes

Comment: Can you please translate me this code to python ?